# req.has_data() is not working in python 3.7

Tags: python, request, python-requests

I have a python code in version 2. Since this version will be coming to an end soon, I want to move it to a higher version.

I have the code:

```
req.has_data()
```

which was working perfectly in python2. 
In Python 3.4 and above, it is not available. 
How can I make this behavior work in python3, I searched some documents, but could not find anything. Please help. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's `req`...

Comment: req  is an instance of `urllib.request.Request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [urllib docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html):

> Changed in version 3.4: The request methods add_data, has_data,
>   get_data, get_type, get_host, get_selector, get_origin_req_host and
>   is_unverifiable that were deprecated since 3.3 have been removed.

Also from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.data), `Request.data` property returns:

> The entity body for the request, or None if not specified.

So you could just replace `req.has_data()` with a truthiness test of `Request.data`.

Of course I've had to make an assumption that `req` in your question is actually an instance of `urllib.request.Request`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now the code is working. But again it is showing error in `req.get_data()` function. I have not worked with requests before. Do you have any kind of mapping of function names between Python2 and Python3 in `Requests` module

Comment: As you can see, `get_data()` is one of the depreciated functions listed above. Again, `Request.data` property would be the alternative to that. As an aside, [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is different to [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.data) and unless you have a strong reason for using the latter, I strongly suggest using the former.

Comment: Thank you @SuperShoot.  If I am not wrong `Request.data` should have returned the data in bytes, not in string. It returning string made me edit my code in so many places.